# Magento 2: main.INFO: Broken reference:

Tags: magento2

I have to clean the logs non-stop because I get a issue all the time the same in 3 stores on magento.

```
[2018-07-26 07:36:56] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'skip_gallery_before' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.media.image', but their parents are different: 'skip_gallery_before.wrapper' and 'product.detail.info' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:36:56] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'skip_gallery_after' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.media.image', but their parents are different: 'skip_gallery_after.wrapper' and 'product.detail.info' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:36:56] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product.info.media.video' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.media.image', but their parents are different: 'product.info.media' and 'product.detail.info' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:36:56] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product.brand.img.sidebar' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:36:56] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.product.related.sidebar' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.brand.img.sidebar', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:38:05] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:38:05] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:38:05] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:38:05] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'custom.sidebar.content' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:38:05] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'minicart' tries to reorder itself towards 'logo', but their parents are different: 'header-wrapper' and 'header' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:38:05] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'custom.sidebar.content' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:41:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:41:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:41:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:41:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'custom.sidebar.content' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:41:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product.brand.img.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:41:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.product.related.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:41:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'minicart' tries to reorder itself towards 'logo', but their parents are different: 'header-wrapper' and 'header' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:41:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'custom.sidebar.content' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:41:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'skip_gallery_before' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.media.image', but their parents are different: 'skip_gallery_before.wrapper' and 'product.detail.info' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:41:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'skip_gallery_after' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.media.image', but their parents are different: 'skip_gallery_after.wrapper' and 'product.detail.info' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:41:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product.info.media.video' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.media.image', but their parents are different: 'product.info.media' and 'product.detail.info' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:41:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product.brand.img.sidebar' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:41:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.product.related.sidebar' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.brand.img.sidebar', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:42:14] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:42:14] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:42:14] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:42:14] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'custom.sidebar.content' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:42:14] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'minicart' tries to reorder itself towards 'logo', but their parents are different: 'header-wrapper' and 'header' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:42:14] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'custom.sidebar.content' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:47:01] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:47:01] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:47:01] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:47:01] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'custom.sidebar.content' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:47:01] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'paypal.partner.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:47:01] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'bml.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:47:01] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'minicart' tries to reorder itself towards 'logo', but their parents are different: 'header-wrapper' and 'header' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:47:01] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'custom.sidebar.content' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:48:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:48:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:48:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:48:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'custom.sidebar.content' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:48:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'paypal.partner.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:48:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'bml.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:48:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'minicart' tries to reorder itself towards 'logo', but their parents are different: 'header-wrapper' and 'header' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:48:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'custom.sidebar.content' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:48:54] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'mgs.instant.search.autocomplete' element cannot be added as child to 'top.search', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:48:54] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'mgs.instant.search.autocomplete' element cannot be added as child to 'top.search', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:48:55] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:48:55] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:48:55] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:48:55] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'custom.sidebar.content' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:48:55] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'minicart' tries to reorder itself towards 'logo', but their parents are different: 'header-wrapper' and 'header' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:48:55] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'custom.sidebar.content' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'global_notices' element cannot be added as child to 'global.notices', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'logo' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'global.search' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'user' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'menu' element cannot be added as child to 'page.menu', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'breadcrumbs' element cannot be added as child to 'page.breadcrumbs', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'formkey' element cannot be added as child to 'page.formkey', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'page.title' element cannot be added as child to 'main.top', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'messages' element cannot be added as child to 'page.messages', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'page.actions.toolbar' element cannot be added as child to 'page.main.actions', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'legal' element cannot be added as child to 'footer', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification_area' element cannot be added as child to 'notifications', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'unread_system_messages' element cannot be added as child to 'notifications', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification_window' element cannot be added as child to 'notifications', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'mirasvit.utils' element cannot be added as child to 'footer', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.right' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.left' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'logo' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'global.search' tries to reorder itself towards 'logo', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'user' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'page.actions.toolbar' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'page.main.actions' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.left' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.right' tries to reorder itself towards 'header.inner.left', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'feedback.button' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'global_notices' element cannot be added as child to 'global.notices', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'logo' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'global.search' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'user' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'menu' element cannot be added as child to 'page.menu', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'breadcrumbs' element cannot be added as child to 'page.breadcrumbs', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'formkey' element cannot be added as child to 'page.formkey', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'page.title' element cannot be added as child to 'main.top', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'messages' element cannot be added as child to 'page.messages', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'page.actions.toolbar' element cannot be added as child to 'page.main.actions', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'legal' element cannot be added as child to 'footer', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification_area' element cannot be added as child to 'notifications', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'unread_system_messages' element cannot be added as child to 'notifications', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification_window' element cannot be added as child to 'notifications', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'mirasvit.utils' element cannot be added as child to 'footer', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.right' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.left' element cannot be added as child to 'header', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'logo' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'global.search' tries to reorder itself towards 'logo', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'user' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'page.actions.toolbar' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'page.main.actions' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.left' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.right' tries to reorder itself towards 'header.inner.left', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:24] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'feedback.button' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:32] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'feedback.button' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 07:50:37] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'feedback.button' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 08:02:39] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 08:02:39] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 08:02:39] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 08:02:39] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'custom.sidebar.content' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 08:02:39] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'paypal.partner.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 08:02:39] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'bml.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 08:02:39] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.leftnav' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.main', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 08:02:39] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'minicart' tries to reorder itself towards 'logo', but their parents are different: 'header-wrapper' and 'header' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 08:02:39] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'custom.sidebar.content' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 08:02:39] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.leftnav' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.main' and '' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 08:07:52] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 08:07:52] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 08:07:52] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 08:07:52] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'custom.sidebar.content' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2018-07-26 08:07:52] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'minicart' tries to reorder itself towards 'logo', but their parents are different: 'header-wrapper' and 'header' respectively. [] []
[2018-07-26 08:07:52] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'custom.sidebar.content' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'sidebar.additional' and '' respectively. [] []
```

Anyone know it is possible to solve this issue ?

Comment: Magento Team has  provided some solutions for Broken Reference can you refer this link https://github.com/malachy-mcconnell/magento2/commit/ac539de0ccaabfa142b5b1e07895158ba1a50140

Comment: Also here check https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/5ceb0820676e4593b68e1991abd348d99adac09c

Comment: @AnsarHusain, that's where they changed it from critical to info level, but it doesn't help us actually fix them.   Maybe try explaining what they are, so we can actually fix them.

Comment: Any solution? I'm using Magento 2.3 and facing the same issue

Comment: I constantly see these errors and it would be great to get a definitive answer on what it's actually trying to tell us. Failing that there is this https://github.com/justbetter/magento2-disable-spam-in-log

Comment: Have u resolved your issue?

Comment: Did you solve the issue @Sylvester

Answer (score 1):

For quick fix, you can just add the following file.

app/design/frontend/vendor_name/theme_name/Magento_Theme/page_layout/1column.xml

with following code.

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
<container name="sidebar.additional" label="Sidebar Additional" htmlTag="div"/>
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional" remove="true"/>
 <container name="sidebar.main" label="Sidebar Main" htmlTag="div"/>
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main" remove="true"/>
```

it will remove following two error from system.log

- Broken reference: sidebar_additional
- Broken reference: sidebar_main

Comment: Could you please explain how it works?

Answer (score 0):

You can search the code for the phrase "Broken reference" to see where most of these messages are being logged.

I had a similar situation where my system log was being overrun by useless log messages. I am sure these are relevant to someone, but I'm using the Luma theme with no modifications, and not really focused on debugging problems that ship with it.

In my particular case, the following code blocks were the culprits:

In vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Data/Structure.php, line 124 (Magento 2.3.2):

```
if ($this->state->getMode() === State::MODE_DEVELOPER) {
    $this->logger->info(
        "Broken reference: the '{$childName}' tries to reorder itself towards '{$sibling}', but " .
        "their parents are different: '{$parentName}' and '{$siblingParentName}' respectively."
    );
}
```

In vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/ScheduledStructure/Helper.php, line 199 (Magento 2.3.2):

```
if ($this->state->getMode() === State::MODE_DEVELOPER) {
    $this->logger->info(
        "Broken reference: the '{$name}' element cannot be added as child to '{$parentName}', " .
        'because the latter doesn\'t exist'
    );
}
```

Note that these are only active when in developer mode. I simply commented out these sections. This is not the ultimate solution, but again, this is not useful information to me at this time and the excessive log chatter is inhibiting the work that I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use this patch to disable those unnecessary logs in developer mode:

```
--- vendor/magento/framework/Cache/InvalidateLogger.php
+++ vendor/magento/framework/Cache/InvalidateLogger.php
@@ -43,7 +43,7 @@
      */
     public function execute($invalidateInfo)
     {
-        $this->logger->debug('cache_invalidate: ', $this->makeParams($invalidateInfo));
+        //$this->logger->debug('cache_invalidate: ', $this->makeParams($invalidateInfo));
     }

     /**
--- vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/ScheduledStructure/Helper.php
+++ vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/ScheduledStructure/Helper.php
@@ -196,7 +196,7 @@
             } else {
                 $scheduledStructure->setElementToBrokenParentList($key);

-                if ($this->state->getMode() === State::MODE_DEVELOPER) {
+                if ($this->state->getMode() === State::MODE_DEVELOPER && false) {
                     $this->logger->info(
                         "Broken reference: the '{$name}' element cannot be added as child to '{$parentName}', " .
                         'because the latter doesn\'t exist'
--- vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Data/Structure.php
+++ vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Data/Structure.php
@@ -121,7 +121,7 @@
             if ($childName !== $sibling) {
                 $siblingParentName = $this->getParentId($sibling);
                 if ($parentName !== $siblingParentName) {
-                    if ($this->state->getMode() === State::MODE_DEVELOPER) {
+                    if ($this->state->getMode() === State::MODE_DEVELOPER && false) {
                         $this->logger->info(
                             "Broken reference: the '{$childName}' tries to reorder itself towards '{$sibling}', but " .
                             "their parents are different: '{$parentName}' and '{$siblingParentName}' respectively."
```

Comment: This hides the issue rather than resolving it.

Answer (score -1):

Try it

```
chown -R [apache-user:apache-group] .; && find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \; && find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
/usr/bin/php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy;
/usr/bin/php bin/magento cache:flush;
```